# Как получить html код страницы?

Tags: python, парсер, request

Я писал парсер и в процессе столкнулся с проблемой: вместо ожидаемого html кода, запрос `requests.get`выдает непонятный набор символов хотя с другими ссылками все работает нормально.
Вот мой код:

```
import requests

HEADERS={
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'
}

html=requests.get('https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-bestandsliste.html?userId=23891705', headers=HEADERS)
print(html.text)
```

вот начало из того что этот код выдает на выходе:

f1xx.v1xx=v1xx;f1xx[374148]=window;f1xx[647467]=e8NN(f1xx[374148]);f1xx[125983]=n3EE(f1xx[374148]);f1xx[210876]=(function(){var P6=2;for(;P6 !== 1;){switch(P6){case 2:return {w3:(function(v3){var v6=2;for(;v6 !== 10;){switch(v6){case 2:var O3=function(W3){var u6=2;for(;u6 !== 13;){switch(u6){case 2:var o3=[];u6=1;break;case 14:return E3;break;case 8:U3=o3.H8NN(function(){var Z6=2;for(;Z6 !== 1;){switch(Z6){case 2:return 0.5 - B8NN.P8NN();break;}}}).D8NN('');E3=f1xx[U3];u6=6;break;case 3:j3++;u6=5;break;case 6:u6=!E3?8:14;break;case 5:u6=j3 Подскажите как мне получить полный html код страницы или где мне стоит поискать ответ на мой вопрос

Comment: Да понятный набор символов. Яваскрипт это. Что вас так удивляет?

Comment: я уже понял что это яваскрипт, но как мне получить html?

Comment: я запустил ваш код и получил html. Не знаю в чем у вас проблема.